# How to redirect page in apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I have centOS 6.3 machine with ABC server installed on apache.. Now by default to access the server i hav to use url: YYYY.XXXX.com/support/admin but instead i want to to use admin.XXXX.com to access it by redirecting page.. Please tell me how shall i creat page re-directs with httpd configurations?

My by default server is in location:

```
/var/www/vhosts/YYYY.XXXX.com/support/
```

Admin folder inside like: `YYYY.XXXX.com/support/admin/`

My httpd.config file contains:

```
ServerName YYYY.XXXX.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/YYYY.XXXX.com/
 ServerName YYYY.XXXX.com
 ErrorLog logs/YYYY.XXXX.com-error_log
 CustomLog logs/YYYY.XXXX.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: A trace of your attempts would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

Add "ServerAlias admin.XXXX.com" to your virtual host.